# What does 'PLS' acronym mean on this CAD drawing?

Tags: eaglecad, cad, drawing

I was making some EAGLE parts and was curious about the highlighted acronym shown in the image below:

[image: Keystone 3557-2 CAD Drawing]

What does it refer to?

[Full Datasheet](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/215/3557-2-287120.pdf)

Comment: It's a very unconventional shorthand for 'repeat this for 4 identical features'. Usually denoted by just a '4x'. Maybe it's short for 'places'

Comment: @user36129 +1 for the answer. Write it up.

Comment: Ah - that was my guess. Was curious about it, since I haven't seen it on other drawings. Thanks!

Comment: you should share the drawings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the "PLS" literally stands for "Places". It is not a standard way of describing it, it is not an ANSI convention, but some people still use it. It just means the part (or hole) in question is the same in X number of places.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience designing in the Automotive design industry, specifically manufacturing machinery and tool & die design, it is still common to see "4 PLCS" or "4 PLS" used for "4 Places" while ASME Y14.5M -1994 standard uses "4X " which is the convention (although I can't see where this is explicitly stated in this GD&T standard.)